# ERROR: LoadError: No working GUI backend found for matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, julia

I have a problem with using PyPlot and plt.gui(true)

My Julia file reads:

```
import PyPlot as plt
plt.pygui(true)
plt.pygui(:qt5)
plt.plot([1,2], [2,4])
end
```

When in the Julia REPL I enter:

include("MyTest.jl")

the code above works and a plot is shown. But when I enter

using MyTest

I get the error message:

```
julia> using MyTest

[ Info: Precompiling MyTest [top-level]
1
2
ERROR: LoadError: No working GUI backend found for matplotlib.
[ Info: Precompiling MyTest [top-level]
```

matplotlib and pyqt5 are installed and PyPlot is added to my packages. I would be very appreciative for any help.

Best regards

Rolf

The stacktrace is:

```
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(s::String)
   @ Base ./error.jl:35
 [2] pygui(b::Bool)
   @ PyPlot ~/.julia/packages/PyPlot/2MlrT/src/init.jl:222
 [3] top-level scope
   @ ~/Projects/LDSS/ldss_jl/LDSSData/src/MyTest.jl:3
 [4] include
   @ ./Base.jl:457 [inlined]
 [5] include_package_for_output(pkg::Base.PkgId, input::String, depot_path::Vector{String}, dl_load_path::Vector{String}, load_path::Vector{String}, concrete_deps::Vector{Pair{Base.PkgId, UInt128}}, source::Nothing)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:2049
 [6] top-level scope
   @ stdin:3
in expression starting at /home/wester/Projects/LDSS/ldss_jl/LDSSData/src/MyTest.jl:1
in expression starting at stdin:3
ERROR: Failed to precompile MyTest [top-level] to "/home/wester/.julia/compiled/v1.9/jl_yY55d4".
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(s::String)
   @ Base ./error.jl:35
 [2] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String, internal_stderr::IO, internal_stdout::IO, keep_loaded_modules::Bool)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:2300
 [3] compilecache
   @ ./loading.jl:2167 [inlined]
 [4] _require(pkg::Base.PkgId, env::String)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1805
 [5] _require_prelocked(uuidkey::Base.PkgId, env::String)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1660
 [6] macro expansion
   @ ./loading.jl:1648 [inlined]
 [7] macro expansion
   @ ./lock.jl:267 [inlined]
 [8] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1611
```

Comment: Sorry  I forgot "module MyTest" in m y post.

Comment: Please edit your post. Most likely your plotting code (all `plt.` calls) should be wrapped into a function.